# Splunk - Disabling alerts during maintenance window

Tags: splunk

I have a simple cvs file loaded in splunk called StandardMaintenance.csv which looks like this...

```
UnderMaintenance
NO
```

We currently get bombarded with alerts during our maintenance window.  At the start of maintenance, I want to be able to change this to YES to stop the alerts (I have an easy way to do this).  I am looking for something standard to add to all alert queries that check this csv for status (lookup as I understand it) and for the query to return nothing if UnderMaintenance = YES, thus not generate a match to the query.

It is basically a binary, ON or OFF.  I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:**

> You cannot disable the alert by executing splunk query because the
>   Rest API requires a POST action.

**Step 1:**  Maintain a csv file of all your savedsearches with owners by using below query. You can schedule the query as per your convenience. For example below search creates *maintenance.csv* and replaces all  contents whenever executed.

```
 | rest /servicesNS/-/search/saved/searches | table title eai:acl.owner | outputlookup maintenance.csv
```

This file would get created in $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/<*app name*>/lookups

**Step 2:** Write a script to read data from *maintenance.csv* file and execute below command to *disable* searches. *(Run before maintenance window)*

```
 curl -X POST -k -u admin:pass https://<splunk server>:8089/servicesNS/<owner>/search/saved/searches/<search title>/disable
```

**Step 3:** Do the same thing to *enable* all seaches, just change the command to below *(Run after maintenance window)*

```
curl -X POST -k -u admin:pass https://<splunk server>:8089/servicesNS/<owner>/search/saved/searches/<search title>/enable
```

### **EDIT 1:**

Create StandardMaintenance.csv file under $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/apps/search/lookups.
The StandardMaintenance.csv file contains :

```
UnderMaintenance
"No"
```

Use below search query to get results of existing saved searches only if ***UnderMaintenance* = No** :

```
| rest /servicesNS/-/search/saved/searches 
| eval UnderMaintenance = "No" 
| table title eai:acl.owner UnderMaintenance
| join UnderMaintenance 
[| inputlookup StandardMaintenance.csv ]
| table title eai:acl.owner
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response.  It provides a way that I could programatically turn the switch on or off.  However, once this switch is set, I need my queries to check this setting and return the appropriate info.  That is what I am looking for (sorry if that wasn't clear).  Basically, can someone provide a sample query that shows how I check the status of UnderMaintenance from the CSV and if YES, return nothing.  If NO, return the normal results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Before each query create a variable (say it's called foo) that you set to true if maintenance is NO and that you do not set otherwise, as below:

```
... | eval foo=case(maintenance=="NO","true")
```

Then you put the below at the end of your query:

```
| eval foo=$foo$
```

This will make your query execute only if maintenance is NO